# hide subdomain in address bar

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, dns, cname

My main website is located on www.example.com. On the subdomain sub.example.com I'm building another website. Both websites are build with WordPress. Both domains are registred at the same registrar

I registered a domainname (lets say: www.example2.com) wich I would like to point to sub.example.com. When someone visites www.example2.com he/she should see www.example2.com in the address bar and not sub.example.com.

I was trying to get this to work with a .htaccess file and it kind of worked, but not in the way I was hoping:

- when I enter example2.com the browser opens sub.example.com and in the address bar it states example2.com (so far, so good)
- when I navigate to another page on the website the address bar shows sub.example.com/another-page instead of example2.com/another-page
- when I enter www.example2.com the browser opens www.example.com

This is how my .htaccess file looks like at the moment:

```
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} example2.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.example2.com$ [NC]

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.example.com [R=301,L]
```

Can someone tell me how I can get this to work?

Comment: Why not just use a CNAME DNS for www.example2.com and point it to sub.example.com?

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see if it works for you. Also I would make sure the `www` dns record for `example2.com` is pointing to the same location as `example2.com`.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?example2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.example.com/$1 [L]
```

Edit:

Really for what you are trying to accomplish, I would suggest NameBased virtual Hosts if possible. That's what it was designed for. So that you can use the same IP for multiple sites. This change is done in the apache config file. See this simple example.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.example.com
ServerAlias example.com *.example.com
DocumentRoot /www/example.com/html
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.example2.com
ServerAlias example2.com
DocumentRoot /www/example.com/html/sub
</VirtualHost>
```

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html

That tells the server what document root to use for each website and therefore eliminates the need for these mod redirects and CNAMEs to sub domains.

Comment: I added the following DNS Records:  
- www.example2.com CNAME sub.example.com 3600  
- example2.com CNAME sub.example.com 3600  
- *.example2.com CNAME sub.example.com 3600  

and replaced my code in the .htaccess file with yours, but it still isn't working

Comment: Well you have a TTL of 3600, if you just changed it, it can take up to an hour for dns to propagate. So you might need to wait before testing www.example2.com. What does your VirtualHost configuration look like?

Comment: Okay, just checked again and now it's pointing to http://sub.example.com/sub. Is this because I changed the DNS records or because of the change in the .htaccess file? I don't know exactly what you need to know about my VirtualHost configuration?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. My English isn't that well ;) When I type www.domain2.com, the browser tries to open up http://sub.example.com/sub

Comment: did you remove the htaccess rules after you added the cname? Do you use a control panel or did you manually configure the virtual hosts?

Comment: I didn't remove the htaccess rules after adding the cname. I use a control panel to configure the virtual host.

Comment: Thank you for all your replies! I don't know where to put the code for the NameBased Virtual Host. And should I delete the changes in the .htaccess file and DNS records?

Comment: It goes in your apache config, not sure if you can do it from a control panel. What OS do you use? Do you have root access?

Comment: I had contact with the host and they told me it's not possible to change anything in the apache config or I need to upgrade.. So I need to figure out what I'm going to do. Thanks for your help anyway!